# finding the PDF of $Y=\sqrt X$

Tags: probability

I have a past exam paper with no solutions. Lots of the questions give a PDF and want me to find a different PDF. I am a bit confused about the exact method of doing this. One example is

$f_x(x)= \lambda e ^{-\lambda x}$, $x>0$

find the PDF of $Y= \sqrt X$

So obviously I know that $y>0$ but i have no idea how to find a PDF in the way. Would i rearrange for $X$ so that i have $X=Y^2$ so i would have something like $P(|X|=Y^2)$?

Could someone please explain exactly how i would solve this so that i can work out how to solve other similar problems? I may be searching wrong but i cannot find anything of a similar nature in my books or coursenotes.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that is more likely the method you need to use.

Comment: I dont know how to go any further to be honest...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with the cdf of $Y$. For $y>0$ you have that $$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(\sqrt{X}\le y)=^{X>0}P(X\le y^2)=F_X(y^2)$$
Now take the derivative to find $f_Y(y)$.It is $$f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_X(y^2)=f_X(y^2)\cdot(y^2)'=2y\lambda e^{-\lambda y^2}$$ for $y>0$ and $f_Y(y)=0$ otherwise. This is the Rayleigh distribution. (Check for mistakes in the calculations).

Comment: thank you very much! So is $f_y(y)$ my answer? What is the eact method for this kind of working out called? I want to be able to apply this to similar questions as i have an exam tomorrow and I am a bit confused about what the exact method for this change of variable type pdf is. Many thanks

Comment: Am i meant to find the CDF first? Sorry i am new to this :)

Comment: How do you go from $P(\sqrt{X}\le y)=P(|X|\le \sqrt{y})?$?

Comment: Sholdn't it be $P(X\le y^2)$?

Comment: Oh, yes true, it should be y^2 yes

Comment: yes it def should! :) he did say check for errors tho! Many thanks. So generally, should i be finding the CDF first then?

Comment: He did!  The technique is spot on...  good luck!  :)

Comment: i know he did! thats why i am asking, what the general way of solving something like this is?

Comment: Yes, check it again, I edited it. Yes, that is what you should do, go for the CDF first and then take derivative! Be carefully on the domain, but it should work. If you are allowed to have a table with the distributions you can then recognize which distribution comes out as I do

Comment: or what this method is called so i can see a general explanation? this is just a practice exam, i have a real exam tomorrow so want to make sure my working out is spot on.

Comment: thank you! yes we will have tables but do not need to say which distribution. What is this type of question called so that i can read up on it? I follow your working out it is great but want to be able to answer any type of this question. Many thanks

Comment: Check here among others http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec1-5.pdf It is called the "distribution function method for transformation of random variables" so that you can google it.

Comment: This is called "transformation of random variables"

Comment: AMAZING! thank you so much :)